# Simple graphical tool for simple program

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm creating a simple program in java and I want to create a graphical user interface. However, I'm not good at programming, so I find it difficult to use java's awt and applet and whatnot. Any tip for software, plugins or another cheat I can use?

Comment: Why did I get so many downvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Netbeans WYSIWYG-Editor.

Comment: But it's true, start learning to programm. You can check out the code the WYSIWYG-Editor creates and learn the basics and maybe some tricks from it ;)

Comment: I am able to do programming, but I have some structural problems. So using a lot of time on jframe/awt/applet is too stressfull for a simple program. Then I would rather let some software do the work for me. But netbeans seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use swing to !programm! simple UI. It has classes like JFrame,JMenu,JButton,JLable,JPabel,JProgressBar,JTextArea,KeyStroke,filechooser all you need to do i check some of tutorials or java docs and start programming.

Here is something to begin with: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

Do not be scared to programm.

Practice makes perfect :)